# How to make checkbox unselected,on slice of pills in datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning datatable.I have check box column in that datatable.Now on selecting records from datatable,i am adding selected records to pills container.
on deselecting,they are removing from the list but the check box is not unchecking.How to make the check box unselected,when i click on X icon on pill.[pills container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYjLk.png)

[image: datatable selection]
Below is my code:

### Component:

```
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsCount" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsDetails" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRowsList" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="maxRowSelection" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="enableInfiniteLoading" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="initialRows" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowsToLoad" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="totalNumberOfRows" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="loadMoreStatus" type="String" default="Please scroll 
    down to load more data"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showRowNumberColumn" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowNumberOffset" type="Integer" default="0"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rowsToAdd" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="currentCount" type="Integer" default="10"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="defaultSortDirection" type="String"/>
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
                             data="{!v.data}"
                             keyField="Id"
                             showRowNumberColumn="true"
                             rowNumberOffset="0"
                             onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}"
                             selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}"
                             maxRowSelection="{!v.maxRowSelection}"
                             onrowselection="{!c.handleSelectedRow}"
                             enableInfiniteLoading="true"
                             loadMoreOffset="{!v.loadMoreOffset}"
                             sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                             sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                             defaultSortDirection="{!v.defaultSortDirection }"
                             onsort="{!c.handleColumnSorting}"
                             onloadmore="{!c.handleLoadMoreContacts}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.selectedlist}" var="sr">
    <lightning:pill class="slds-m-around_xx-small" label="{!sr.name}" name="{!sr.Id}" onremove="{!c.clear}">
    <aura:set attribute="media">
    <lightning:icon iconName="standard:Account" size="Large"/>
    </aura:set>
    </lightning:pill>
    </aura:iteration>
```

### controller:

```
clear :function(component,event,heplper){
        var selectedPillId = event.getSource().get("v.name");
        var AllPillsList = component.get("v.selectedlist"); 

        for(var i = 0; i < AllPillsList.length; i++){
            if(AllPillsList[i].Id == selectedPillId){
                AllPillsList.splice(i, 1);
                component.set("v.selectedlist", AllPillsList);
            }  
        }
handleSelectedRows: function (component, event, helper) {
    var data = component.get('v.data');
    var selectedRowList =  component.get("v.selectedRowsList");
    console.log('selectedRowList-' + selectedRowList);
},

handleSelectedRow: function(component, event, helper){
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
    component.set("v.selectedRowsCount", selectedRows.length);
    let obj =[] ; 
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++){
        obj.push({Name:selectedRows[i].Name});
    }
    component.set("v.selectedRowsDetails", JSON.stringify(obj) );
    component.set("v.selectedRowsList", event.getParam('selectedRows'));
    },
```

How to make datatable checkbox unselected on deselection of pills.

Comment: Please include the section of your component markup where you declare your data table and its associated attributes.

Comment: http://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/07/infinite-loading-in-lightningdatatable.html.i added attributes same as this link

Comment: We need to see *your* code and *your* effort to solve this problem in the body of your question, not through a link to a third-party site. Would you take a few minutes to look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and add this information through an edit?

Comment: I added attributes too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically select rows by populating the component attribute that you have bound to the `<lightning:dataTable>`'s `selectedRows` property. That property should be a list of the values you've defined as the `keyField` of the data table.

From the [Component Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation):

> The `selectedRows` attribute enables programmatic selection of rows, which is useful when you want to preselect rows.
>
> To select a row programmatically, pass in the row `keyField` value.
>
> ```
>     var rows = ['a'];
>     cmp.set('v.selectedRows', rows);
> ```

Your `clear()` function already implements filtering based on the Id for the attribute `selectedlist`. To extend this to control the selected rows, you'd simply need to extract a list of the `Id` attribute for each pill in `selectedlist`, and then set the attribute.

```
component.set("v.selectedRows", component.get("v.selectedlist").map(s => s.Id));
```